# Validation of CXF GET requests against XSD

Tags: java, validation, rest, xsd, cxf

Is there any way to validate GET requests i.e. Query Parameters against a XML Schema. For POST we can have schemaLocations configuration is there something similar for GET. I want this validation to happen before my service class method is invoked.

Comment: How do you define a XML Schema for URL parameters anyway? Notice, that in GET request you are not passing an XML document, it's just plain values.

Comment: i know, actually  the situation is that in my webservice  I have POJOs mapped to GET and POST requests. So while POST i can get the request validated during conversion using schemalocation tag, hence i was thinking  something similar for GET also.

Comment: While I don't think it's possible with GET, I think, you could implement some validation with jsr303 bean validation. Not sure if it works with CXF though.

Comment: @npe Why not on GET? I've passed XML (a complex query filter pattern) as GET parameter.  It was an annotated POJO.

Comment: @unhillbilly See [jsr339](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339). Among others it says that JAX-RS 1.1 has limited validation possibilities, and that JAX-RS 2.0 will validate input using Beans Validation (which is jsr2303)